# Open Web Browser in Background

Tags: python

To open a web browser, I currently use xdg-open inside a python app. However the web browser steals focus. The Python webbrowser module is unreliable so how could I use xdg-open without the browser stealing focus?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `-iconic` flag to your command, even though some window managers may choose to ignore it but I believe Unity acknowledges it.